# Removing duplicate rows from a shapefile

Tags: arcobjects, shapefile, c#, geoprocessing

I would like to write some c# code to delete duplicate rows from a shapefile stored in a folder.

Can anyone provide me with an example or pointers on the best way to attempt this, please?

Comment: how do you define duplicate?

Comment: duplicate geometry or duplicate attribute?

Comment: Actually i used clip method from IBasiGeoProcessor interface to clip a shapefile with a given boundary. The output shapefile shows some duplicate rows(i.e., two fid denoting same feature).

Comment: Perhaps you can provide some screenshots of the geometry being affected. Most likely they are legitimate features that were split during the clip operation.

Comment: @Navish, a simple google search (e.g. arcobjects find dupoicate featuers) should give you a number of code snippets of how to do this.

Comment: @Navish - aren't the duplicate fids representing mutli-part geometries? are you sure you want to remove that?

Comment: @vinayan - yes sir, you are right. Actually, a road feature is carrying two fid for it, each fid representing a part of road(i.e., road is now shown as comprising of two parts) whereas it should have been represented by one fid only. Any workaround available there, i shall be thankful to you.

Answer (score 2):

To remove duplicate geometry with different fid you may use an algorithm like:

```
List<IFeature> features = GetAllFeatures(featureClass)
foreach(var feature in features)
{
    string query = "OIDFieldName = feature.OID";
    List<IFeature> queryFeatures = GetFeaturesBasedOnQuery(featureClass, query);
    foreach(var queryFeature in queryFeatures)
    {
         List<IFeature> sameLocationFeatures = GetFeaturesBySameLocation(featureClass, queryFeature.Shape);
         for (int i = 1; i < sameLocationFeatures.Count; i++)
         {
                    sameLocationFeatures[i].Delete();
         }
    }       
}
```

To get features based on location you may use following code snippent:

```
    public IFeatureCursor GetFeaturesBySameLocation(IFeatureClass featureClass, IGeometry queryGeometry)
    {
        string shapeFieldName = featureClass.ShapeFieldName;
        ISpatialFilter spatialFilter = new SpatialFilter();
        spatialFilter.Geometry = queryGeometry;
        spatialFilter.SpatialRel = esriSpatialRelEnum.esriSpatialRelIntersects;
        spatialFilter.set_OutputSpatialReference(shapeFieldName, spatialReferance);

        IFeatureCursor featureCursor = featureClass.Search(spatialFilter, false);
        return featureCursor ;
    }
```

Code snippet for getting all features of a layer:

```
    public IFeatureCursor GetAllFeatureOfLayer(IFeatureClass featureClass)
    {
        IFeatureCursor featureCursor = featureClass.Search(null, false);
        return featureCursor;
    }
```

Code snippet for getting features based on query from a layer:

```
    public IFeatureCursor GetFeaturesBasedOnQuery(IFeatureClass featureClass, string query)
    {
        IQueryFilter queryFilter = new QueryFilterClass();        
        queryFilter.WhereClause = query;
        IFeatureCursor featureCursor = featureClass.Search(queryFilter, false);

        return featureCursor;
    }
```

Comment: This algorithm will delete (all-1) features in a same location.

Comment: @Navish: Doesn't this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I have a python code to delete duplicate geometry..

code snippet:

```
gp.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(featureverticeshp_Layer, "NEW_SELECTION", gbgquery)    
gp.SelectLayerByLocation_management(featureverticeshp_Layer, "ARE_IDENTICAL_TO", featureverticeshp_Layer, "", "NEW_SELECTION")    
gp.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(featureverticeshp_Layer, "REMOVE_FROM_SELECTION", gbgquery)    
gp.DeleteFeatures_management(featureverticeshp_Layer)
```

If you want I can provide the entire code (author name: Gerry Gabrisch). (I forgot from where I download it, but works fine with shape file).

Answer (score -5):

Now just convert this shape file tp featureclass and open this using Access and find out those duplicate records and delete those..

Comment: It sounds like a programmatic solution is being asked for. Besides, messing with a personal geodatabase feature class's attribute table in Access is likely to corrupt it.

Comment: Actually same feature is being denoted by two or in some cases more than two fid.